# Laravel Blade template on c9 is only selectively extending to certain pages

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-blade, c9.io

My blade template is extending to the index.blade.php with no problem, but doesn't extend to create.blade.php at all which is located in the subfolder.  It simply displays the "Create Users" and nothing else.  I'm currently using Laravel 5.2 and PHP 5.5.

Following is my **admin.blade.php** which is the layout template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Admin</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->

    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/libs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/app.css') }}">-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/libs.css') }}">-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/bootstrap.css') }}">-->
    <!--<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!--<link href="{{asset('css/libs.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!--<link href="/css/blog-post.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
    <!--<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
    <!--<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
    <!--<link href="/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
    <!--<link href="/css/metisMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
    <!--<link href="/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
    <!--<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">-->


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="admin-page">

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-header -->



        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">


            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->


        </ul>






        {{--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">--}}
        {{--@if(auth()->guest())--}}
        {{--@if(!Request::is('auth/login'))--}}
        {{--<li><a href="{{ url('/auth/login') }}">Login</a></li>--}}
        {{--@endif--}}
        {{--@if(!Request::is('auth/register'))--}}
        {{--<li><a href="{{ url('/auth/register') }}">Register</a></li>--}}
        {{--@endif--}}
        {{--@else--}}
        {{--<li class="dropdown">--}}
        {{--<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ auth()->user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span></a>--}}
        {{--<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">--}}
        {{--<li><a href="{{ url('/auth/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>--}}

        {{--<li><a href="{{ url('/admin/profile') }}/{{auth()->user()->id}}">Profile</a></li>--}}
        {{--</ul>--}}
        {{--</li>--}}
        {{--@endif--}}
        {{--</ul>--}}





        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li class="sidebar-search">
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/admin"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i>Users<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/users">All Users</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="/users/create">Create User</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Posts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/posts">All Posts</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="/posts/create">Create Post</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i>Categories<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/categories">All Categories</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="/categories/create">Create Category</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i>Media<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/media">All Media</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">Upload Media</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>







                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="icons.html"> Icons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a class="active" href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>





    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/profile"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>Profile</a>
                </li>




                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Posts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="">All Posts</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="">Create Post</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>





            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>






<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header"></h1>

                @yield('content')
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/metisMenu.js"></script>
<!--<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->


@yield('footer')





</body>

</html>
```

Following is my **create.blade.php**:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')




@section('content')


    <h1>Create Users</h1>



@stop
```

Following is my **AdminUsersController**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\User;

class AdminUsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();    

       return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.users.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return view('admin.users.show');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('admin.users.edit');

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And finally my **route**:

```
Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');`
```

Following is the picture of my [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1agF.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share what's inside `index.blade.php`

Comment: index.blade.php is essentially the same as create.blade.php except instead of Create Users it has Index written on it.

Comment: Share index.blade.php contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@extends('path_to_index.blade.php')` will fix your problem if `create.blade.php` extends `index.blade.php`. If `create.blade.php` extends `main.blade.php` and `index.blade.php` extends `create.blade.php` then you should extend `index.blade.php`.